# Issue on Adding Feature to Open MXD in Real Time Using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy

I am using this code to add a feature from GeoDatabase dataset to an open MXD file

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Temp\Streets.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
targetGroupLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Main", df)[0]
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\Data\NetMap.gdb\Streets\OneWay")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetGroupLayer, addLayer, "BOTTOM")‍‍‍‍‍‍
```

‍
‍This is somehow adding the `OneWay` feature class to the `Main` Group Layer at `Streets.mxd` but I have to close the map and reopen it to see the data there.

I tried to refresh the TOC and Active view like (As it work in IDE inside the Current Map)

```
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

‍
‍

but it is not doing anything with stand-alone script and MXD. Can you please let me know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: To add a layer to an *open* MXD I believe you need to run the python script tool from within ArcMap, and use `mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")`.  Otherwise your arcpy is running in a different process and hits file or application locks.

Comment: What error do you get when you try to do this?  I would expect that to lead you pretty much straight to a duplicate.

Comment: I am not getting any Error! on this and as I said it is adding the layer to the map but not in real time and I have to close the map and re-open it to see the added map